# JavaScript Web Speech API: How can I need the value?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am currently learning Speech Recognition(JavaScript).

I want to make a assistant with JavaScript. My problem is that everything I say I can not use. And I want that to start the function ai() when I say Hello.

My Code:

```
function tsCheck(){
    if (window.transcript == "Hi"){
        ai();
    }
}
function speak(a){
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(a);
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
function ai(){
    speak('How are you?');
    if (window.transcript == "good"){
        speak("cool");
    }

}

var SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true;

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var current = event.resultIndex;
    window.transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;
    console.log(window.transcript);
}

recognition.start();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the problem is?

Comment: if I say "hi" then the function does not start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call the `tsCheck()` function in your `recognition.onresult` callback.

```
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var current = event.resultIndex;
    window.transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;
    tsCheck(); //ADD THIS
    console.log(window.transcript);
}
```

EDIT: in the `tsCheck` method, you need to compare the result to a lowercase string (notice "hi" instead of "Hi".

```
function tsCheck(){
    if (window.transcript == "hi"){
        ai();
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: To keep responding to inputs, I added a parameter to the `ai()` function. This isn't of any real practical use, however, because it doesn't keep track of the context of the conversation.

```
function ai(string){
    speak(string);
}
function tsCheck(){
    if (/hi/i.test(window.transcript)){
        ai("How are you");
    }

    if (/good/i.test(window.transcript)){
        ai("Cool");
    }
}
```

Also using a regex to test the strings, as it sometimes has spaces before and after the word.

Comment: thank you, and how for this ** speak('How are you?'); ** ?